# Is there any linear fractional transformation with this?

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

i wanna find linear transformation which sends -1, i, 1 to -2, i, 2 respectively.

first, i don't know if i could say LT and LFT(linear fractional transformation) to be equivalent.

and if i could consider it as LFT, then i can not solve the coefficient of az+b/cz+d

then it doesnt have such LFT? or i did sone mistake in my calculation?

if there is such LFT, i will be really appreciate if you write the whole procedure to find it

thank you

Comment: They are *not* equivalent. There is no LT with this property, but there is a LFT. *Any* triple of distinct points from $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ can be mapped on any other given triple of points from $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ by a unique LFT.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $f_{z_0z_1z_2}(z)=\frac{z-z_0}{z-z_2}\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_1-z_0}$ (or the limit of this expression if one of $z_0,z_1,z_2$ is $\infty$). Then $f_{z_0z_1z_2}$ maps $(z_0,z_1,z_2)$ to $(0,1,\infty)$. You can verify that every fractional linear transformation (such as $f_{z_0z_1z_2}$) is invertible by considering $g(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and inverting the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)$, whose determinant is nonzero by assumption. Thus, to find a fractional linear transformation mapping $(z_0,z_1,z_2)$ to $(w_0,w_1,w_2)$ you can compute
$f_{w_0w_1w_2}^{-1}\circ f_{z_0z_1z_2}$.